# ActiveX vs Delphi, which is better?

Tags: delphi, activex

I'm making a program and I need to use another program's API.

Which then let me pick between their activeX or Delphi.

Wondering which one I should utilize or focus more on.

Not sure if I'm being too broad here.

Edit: I'm more familiar with visual studio if that is of any concern.

Comment: You can't really compare ActiveX to Delphi. You are definitely being too *unclear* here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi is a programming language. If they're offering ActiveX or Delphi, they're offering you a COM object you can use from any language capable of using it (including Delphi) or a Delphi-specific implementation or interface to the library. Your question is pretty meaningless - "Which shall I take, the apple or the orange?".

If you're programming in Delphi, take the Delphi API; if not, or if you just prefer working with the ActiveX instead, choose it.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot more clearer now.